# Interface problem when using WinForm in WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

[image]

this is my winForm in Visual Studio when i run project and open this form style is changing. Does anyone know what is the problem?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your windows theme in your desktop settings, that might be the problem if the designer doesn't detect them at design time.